Detecting Elevation Requirements in Newly Laucnhed Processes
I'm developing a process monitoring program that identifies processes requiring elevation.
My current approach involves:

GUI Thread to handle the user interface.
Monitoring Thread utilises Event Tracing for Windows to listen for process creation events. This thread communicates new process IDs wrapped as Process classes to the GUI thread.
Elevation Check: The Process class constructor immediately also checks its manifest file to look for relevant information, including <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" /> to determine if the process needs elevations.

This works for many processes, but some executables (e.g., .msi installers) require elevation without explicitly stating it in their manifest (if they have any).
I considered monitoring for consent.exe and svchost.exe invocations:

but a problem arises when multiple processes requiring elevation launch other processes.
If one of these descendant processes triggers constent.exe, it becomes difficult to pinpoint the original process responsibile for the elevation request, this led me to consider a Process Explorer- like aproach to map process trees, but I'm wary of the complexity and potential performance overhead.
Is this a sensible direction, or are there simple, more efficient alternatives to identify processes requiring elevation?
Currently, I encapsulated the ETW logic within a class, and a filtering mechanism to identify relevant processes:
// Process Listener Thread:
void ProcessListener::onRecord(EVENT_RECORD *record) {
    if ( record->EventHeader.EventDescriptor.Id == EVENT_TRACE_TYPE_START ) {
        EventParser parser( record );
        auto &p_info = parser.getTraceEventInfo();

        for ( auto i = 0u; i < p_info->TopLevelPropertyCount; i++ ) {
            const auto current = p_info->EventPropertyInfoArray[ i ];
            const auto property = std::wstring( reinterpret_cast< LPWSTR >( p_info.data() + current.NameOffset ) );

            if ( current.nonStructType.InType == TDH_INTYPE_UNICODESTRING ) {
                if ( property == L"ImageName" ) {
                    auto data = parser.getPropertyData( property );
                    auto path = std::wstring( reinterpret_cast< const wchar_t * >( data.data() ),
                                              data.size() / sizeof( wchar_t ) - 1 );

                    try {
                        Process process( record->EventHeader.ProcessId, path );
                        if ( filter_func != nullptr ) {
                            if ( filter_func( process ) ) {
                                queue.push( std::make_unique< Process >( std::move( process ) ) );
                            }
                        }
                        else { queue.push( std::make_unique< Process >( std::move( process ) ) ); }
                    }
                    catch ( const std::exception &e ) { spdlog::info(e.what()); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// GUI Thread:
psm.setFilter( [] (const ProcessBase &process)-> bool {
        return process.getPath().extension() == ".exe" &&
               process.needsElevation() && // Checks the manifest file.
               process.getPath().wstring().find( L"\\Windows\\System32" ) == std::wstring::npos;
} );
psm.run();


This sounds like a fun project.  There might be a different approach if you can share why you need to track processes requiring elevation.  Also have a read of Old New Thing - There are really only two effectively distinct settings for the UAC slider and Old New Thing - How can I detect that the system is no longer showing a UAC prompt? which describes how UAC elevation can be tracked in some cases

"some executables (e.g., .msi installers) require elevation without explicitly stating it in their manifest" - UAC has an Installer Detection feature that uses heuristics to detect installers who don't use requestedExecutionLevel. Unfortunately, Microsoft does not publish the full details of the heuristics they use.

Thanks to both of you! @RemyLebeau, I appreciate you pointing out that feature – I hadn't come across it before. I'm definitely going to check it out.

Does it work for you now?

Hi @Ax1le. I still haven't figured it out, but I came up with somewhat of a solution.

I'm going to start with the easiest and fastest approach: checking the manifest of the file.
⁠In case 1 doesn't work, I’ll check for its details for 'install', 'setup' and other keywords.
⁠If that doesn't work, a process loads dlls into its memory with different memory locations, when an UAC prompt happen it launches consent.exe with those memory locations, so I'll monitor for that too. I'll write a proper/better response explaining what I'm doing when I have the code working.

